# How can I give an argument without knowing its name to a multiparameter function? Python

Tags: python, function, arguments, keyword-argument

Hi I have a multiparameter function where only one parameter is missing in a kwargs and I want to be able to input the missing parameter without knowing what parameter it is:

```
def function(a,b,c):    #multiparameter function
    print('a=',a)
    print('b=',b)
    print('c=',c)

kwargs={'a':1,'b':2}    #only the value for c is missing
```

If I run 
`function(3,**kwargs)` it interprets that `a=3` but I want it to interpret that `c=3`

Alternatively I could find out the name of the missing variable but I cannot manage to feed it correctly to the function. I tried to do:

```
variable='c'

function(variable=3,**kwargs)
```

But it returns the error `function() got an unexpected keyword argument 'variable'`

Comment: You can provide a variable as a key to your `kwargs` dict. e.g., `variable = 'c'; kwargs = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, variable: 3}`. Keep in mind that the ordering matters: if `variable = 'a'`, then `a` will get the value `3`, not `1` and `c` is still unspecified.

Comment: I want to to run the function various times in a go, similar to this:

Comment: np.array([function(c=3,**kwargs),function(c=4,**kwargs)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't modify the definition of `function`, you can wrap it with `functools.partial`.

```
from functools import partial

def function(a,b,c):    #multiparameter function
    print('a=',a)
    print('b=',b)
    print('c=',c)

function_caller = partial(function, 1, 2, 3)
```

Now, any *keyword* arguments to `function_caller` will override the values specified in the call to `partial`:

```
function_caller()  # function(1,2,3)
function_caller(a=5, b=4) # function(5, 4, 3)
kwargs = {'a': 5, 'b': 4}
function_caller(**kwargs)  # Same as previous call
```

If you have `variable` that contains the *name* of a parameter, you can easily add that to `kwargs`, though you can't use it directly as a keyword argument.

```
variable = 'c'
kwargs = {'a': 5, 'b': 4, variable: 3}  # {'a': 5, 'b': 4, 'c': 3}
```

`function_caller`, though, does not accept *any* positional arguments.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without external libraries?

Comment: `functools` is part of the standard library; it's already installed, so there's really no drawback to using it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should probably read about [*args and **kwargs](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/)

You can force you parameters to be keyword parameters with  `*` and each of your keyword param can have a default sentinel value to help you spot it.

```
def function(*,a = None,b = None,c = None)
    print('a=',a)
    print('b=',b)
    print('c=',c)
```

If you want to input something on the fly you could do:

```
def function(input, *,a = None,b = None,c = None)
    print('a=',a or input)
    print('b=',b or input)
    print('c=',c or input)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can take the parameter as a variable, then this request:

> ```
> kwargs={'a':1,'b':2}    #only the value for c is missing
> variable='c'
> function(variable=3,**kwargs)
> ```

Can work if you just add the variable to the kwargs dictionary:

```
kwargs[variable] = 3
function(**kwargs)
```

Comment: what I want to do is run the function quickly various times without having to change the kwargs in a similar way to this:  np.array([function(variable=3,**kwargs),function(variable=4,**kwargs),function(variable=5,**kwargs)])